# How to add members to an existing definition in flowjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowtype

TypeScript seems to have an important little feature that lets you add members to an existing interface definition. In interfaces, the members are additive so if you define interface with a set of members you can define the interface a second time to add additional members to the interface.

I have a predefined external flowjs definition file like this:

```
declare class JQueryStatic {
  ajax(url: string, settings?: any): any;
}
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

And would now like to add a new method `myPlugin(settings?: any): any;` to the class JQueryStatic.

That's the key to supporting jQuery plugins in a strongly typed way.

What is the suggested way to do this in flow?

Comment: Please read the `flow-js` tag description -- it's not for `flowtype`

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersection is the way to go.

First we need base definition for jquery, let's say it looks like this:

```
// here we declare shape of jquery
declare class $GlobalJquery {
   foo(): void
}

// here we declare global reference to jquery
declare var $: $GlobalJquery;
```

Next thing we need is to declare shape of plugin somewhere:

```
interface SomeJqueryPlugin {
  bar(): void;  // plugin adds bar() function to jquery
}
```

And at last, we redeclare `$` when we need to use plugin functionality:

```
declare var $: $GlobalJquery & SomeJqueryPlugin;

$.foo();
$.bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Intersection types might work for you.

```
type A = { foo: string; };
type B = { bar: string; };
type AB = A & B;
```

AB has for type `{ foo: string; bar: string;}`;

From https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1265 (see "Intersection Type")

Comment: This will not work. Because `AB` will not change how something of type `A` behaves. (assuming `A` is what `jquery.flowtype` would provide)

Comment: If I had an example to go off I could maybe understand the problem better, I don't use jquery myself (no smugness intended).

Comment: @Nikita I've added a simple example

Comment: @Nikita Your intersection creates a new type AB but I would need to add properties to the existing type A in flowjs.

Comment: @materialdreams Ah, I see now. Sorry, as far as I know there is no way to change an existing type other than to edit its actual definition., e.g. by using your own personal fork of the `jquery-flow-interface` project that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an open issue about creating such declaration files : https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2421

It hasn't received any attention but it might (its only been 5 days till yet)

Comment: It just seems a very generic problem, so I've tried here as well. I'm new to flowjs and expected this to be a no-brainer for flowjs experts.